# Запись и отправка звука на сервер javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc, blob

Нужно записать голосовое сообщение с микрофона и отправить его на сервер. Пытался использовать библиотеку Recorder.js, но она создает blob объект на стороне клиента и выдает ссылку на его скачивание.

```
        function createDownloadLink() {
        recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var au = document.createElement('audio');
            var hf = document.createElement('a');

            au.controls = true;
            au.src = url;
            hf.href = url;
            hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
            hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
            li.appendChild(au);
            li.appendChild(hf);
            recordingslist.appendChild(li);
        });
    }
```

Вот функция, которая это делает. Само веб-приложение у меня написано на mvc 5 C#.
Я пытался добавить созданный blob объект в input file его передавать, но это тоже не получилось. Может кто-нибудь показать как это сделать? Или подсказать другое решение, не используя эту библиотеку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blob может быть отправлен на сервер через [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
var req = new Request('/url/for/upload', { method: 'POST', body: blob });
fetch(req).then(
    () => console.log('Файл сохранен'), 
    () => console.log('Ошибка сохранения')
);
```

Comment: Павел, я пытался отправить через $.post объект url который создается из blob, но на сервере я так получаю только сроку. Как мне передать сам звук?

Comment: @Vivus где вы в моем ответе видели $.post или createObjectURL?

Comment: Нет, я говорил о том, что делал я. Записал Вашу функцию, пара вопросов.
1. '/url/for/upload' - тут должно быть название метода действия контроллера?
2. Как мне в контроллере получить этот объект?

Comment: @Vivus 1. А что еще там может быть?

Comment: @Vivus 2. Если отправлять именно в таком виде - в контроллере надо читать Request.InputStream

Comment: Просто я поставил в этот метод точку останова, он не ловит. Я поэтому спрашивал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65653/discussion-between-vivus-and-pavel-mayorov).